# multiple Tabs with interrupt in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I break my Arduino project into multiple tabs files to make it more clear.
I have the main Tab(file) and to other Tab (A and B). the are interrupts define in A and B. How can I call in the main Tab? Does anyone have some idea?

Comment: do you have some error message?

Answer (score -1):

Consider all tabs as one large program, just make sure they are named .ino or else they are not part of the program.